# android i got an exception for SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android

Following is the exception

```
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:805)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:944)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at com.s5.selfiemonkey1.helper.LoginHelper.getOfflineData(LoginHelper.java:71)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at com.s5.selfiemonkey1.fragment.PollImageFragment.onCreateView(PollImageFragment.java:165)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
08-28 01:38:41.164: E/StrictMode(1308):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**[EDIT]**
Code:

```
public String getOfflineData(String type){ 
    String offlineData = null; Cursor cursor = null; 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    try { 
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select datavalue from offline_data where type='"+type+"'", null); 
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           offlineData= cursor.getString(0); 
        } 
        cursor.close(); 
     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); 
     } finally { 
        if(cursor!=null) cursor.close(); 
        db.close(); 
     }
     return offlineData; 
}
```

Comment: You have used SQLite and then you didn't closed the databse thats why this error is happening ,check line 71 in LoginHelper.java and also in handler if you have open SQLite there then closed it after use

Comment: i have closed my database but it didn't wor for me

Comment: can you show your SQLite class where you have implemented OpenDBHelper

Comment: public String getOfflineData(String type) {
  String offlineData = null;
  Cursor cursor = null;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  try {
   cursor = db.rawQuery(
     "select datavalue from offline_data where type='" + type
       + "'", null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    offlineData = cursor.getString(0);
   }
   cursor.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   if (cursor != null)
    cursor.close();
   db.close();
  }
  return offlineData;
 }

Comment: @ganeshpatil Have you noticed that you're calling `cursor.close()` twice? Also, please paste the code in your question. It's extremely hard to read it when you just past code in the comment section. If you'd like people to help you, take the effort to make it easier for them to help you.

Comment: yes i have opened cursor that i am closing

Comment: @ganeshpatil - You're opening the cursor that you're closing? I'm not sure what the means. Anyway, try removing the `if(cursor!=null) cursor.close();` from your `finally` block.

Comment: i made a simple mistake to closing cursor twice .

Comment: Edit your post again and post your sql data file also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close your database connection.
Use following structure.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
try {
  --
  --  
} catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  db.close();
}
```

Comment: what if I don't want to close it after every transaction? I want to keep it open until the app stops. How can I stop this warning?