# java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am retrieving data from Sqlite database , code work perfectly but i am getting this exception in my log

**Open database java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace** and **dispose database false
    java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace**

how i can solve this issue, thank you..!

here is my code

```
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + GroupList.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +" ( " + whereParamOnline + " ) " + " ORDER BY " + GroupList.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        List<GroupList> notes = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    GroupList note = new GroupList();
                    note.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_ID)));
                    note.setGroup_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_GROUP_ID)));
                    note.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_NAME)));
                    note.setUser_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_USER_ID)));
                    note.setPicture(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_PICTURE)));
                    note.setNotification(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_NOTIFICATION)));
                    note.setTotal_member(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_TOTAL_MEMBER)));
                    note.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GroupList.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
                    notes.add(note);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"(getAllGroupList) catch error = "+e.getMessage().toString());
        }
        finally {
            db.close();
        }
        // return notes list
        return notes;
```

here is log

```
08-17 18:52:53.156 30409-30409/com.selfie.life.selfielife D/SQLiteDatabase: Open database
        java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:815)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:578)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.selfie.life.selfielife.SqliteDatabase.GroupList.GroupListDatabaseHelper.getAllGroupList(GroupListDatabaseHelper.java:135)
            at com.selfie.life.selfielife.Fragment.MessageChat.ChatRecentFragment$8.onResponse(ChatRecentFragment.java:446)
            at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
    08-17 18:52:53.166 30409-30409/com.selfie.life.selfielife D/SQLiteDatabase: dispose database false
        java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dispose(SQLiteDatabase.java:286)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onAllReferencesReleased(SQLiteDatabase.java:280)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.releaseReference(SQLiteClosable.java:74)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.close(SQLiteClosable.java:106)
            at com.selfie.life.selfielife.SqliteDatabase.GroupList.GroupListDatabaseHelper.getAllGroupList(GroupListDatabaseHelper.java:163)
            at com.selfie.life.selfielife.Fragment.MessageChat.ChatRecentFragment$8.onResponse(ChatRecentFragment.java:446)
            at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: `} while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();db.close();`

Comment: no , still same problem

Comment: Read `npurushe's` comment  https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/issues/41

Comment: still same scenario

Comment: i read comment on github , and i want to tell you that i am not getting explicit error message to close the cursor or database. only it give me `Open database
        java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace` message. when i search about it,i came accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264068/android-i-got-an-exception-for-sqlitedatabase) solution. then i put my `db.close()` into final block.